# t-distribution and Degrees of freedom

Tags: statistical-inference

Why  t- distribution have n-1 degrees of freedom? I know that it is used when population variance is not known but what determines n-1

Comment: As a rule of thumb you lose a degree of freedom for every parameter of the distribution you use estimated from the sample.

Comment: I mean how shape vary as per degrees of freedom. what shape has to do with it.

Comment: Looking for down to earth answer. I am not statistician.